# Drop down to zero during ride

Tags: honda, transmission, diagnostics, voltage

Randomly during ride, the "D" from transmission indicator disappears for 2-3 seconds, during this time the car like switched to neutral (RPM raise without acceleration of the car).

In the beginning I tried to catch some transmission/crankshaft/camshaft sensor issue, but found that all the system just drop to zero for a moment (like you can see in the screenshots).

I tried to find some contact problem of accumulator cables (+ and -), hood and cabin fuses box and key switch connectors when car turned on in parking.

Nothing reproduce the issue. 
The issue doesn't leave any error code.

Honda Jazz/Fit CVT 2006

Any suggestions are welcome

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow. Weird. I think you are on the right track. Its got to be an intermittent connection somewhere. Possible to set up your reader to read battery voltage (key on, engine OFF) use a small rubber hammer and start gently tapping every thing that carries electrons in the car?  I gotta believe you can safely search for the root cause that way. Let us know what you find.